# Opencv Determine 4 outermost corner lines from a rectangular object

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I am using this code to find the 4 **outermost lines** in order get the *corners* of a rectangular object in an image.

```
cv::Mat input(toOcv(surface));
cv::Mat output;

cv::medianBlur(input, output, 21);
Mat dst, cdst;
Canny(input, dst, 50, 200, 3);
cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

//Standard Hough
vector<Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 100, 0, 0);

// Draw the lines
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
    Point pt1, pt2;
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000 * (-b));
    pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000 * (a));
    pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000 * (-b));
    pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000 * (a));

    line(cdst, pt1, pt2, Scalar(rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255), 2, CV_AA);
```

}

[image: This is the original Image.]

I have used Standard Hough Transform to detect the lines.

Now I have too many lines but I want only 4 outermost lines so I can detect corners of the image. 
[image: image result]

Any help would be appreciated !!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that there is no exact solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably are able to find the two main directions corresponding to the sides, or at least an approximation (you can do that by clustering the line angles).

Then from the center of the image, draw two lines in these directions and find the intersections with the relevant Hough lines. Then you can keep the four intersections furthest from the origin.

If the center of the image isn't guaranteed to be inside the quadrilateral, it might be better to first estimate a better center by averaging the intersections (red and violet points) and using the meeting points of the lines through the averages (green point).

[image]